# React TransitionGroup using nodeRef with key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, ref

Im trying to create a simple animation with TransitionGroup and CSSTransition but it behaves unexpectedly unless I remove the nodeRef of the CSSTransition.

(by unexpectedly I mean that the style is not applied or both exitActive and enterActive css classes are applied on the same element. when I remove the nodeRef it works but I get the error '*Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode.*')

I found [this](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-prop-nodeRef) and it explains that

> When changing key prop of Transition in a TransitionGroup a new nodeRef need to be provided to Transition with changed key prop

So the question is:

- Where should I put the new ref when key (dayIndex) changes?
- Do I have to create an array of refs for each element in props.days?

This is the code:

```
const [dayIndex, setDayIndex] = useState(0);
const someRef = useRef(null)

...

return (
...
<TransitionGroup component={null}>
   <CSSTransition nodeRef={someRef} key={dayIndex} classNames={styles} timeout={1000}>
      <div ref={someRef} className="...">
         {props.days[dayIndex]}
      </div>
   </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
...
)
```

(props.days is an array of elements)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work.
each item in the props.days needs its own component with CSSTransition and its own nodeRef and the content with the same ref. to select which item will show use the "in" property.

example:

```
function Animation(props) {
   const ref = useRef(null);
   
    return (
    <CSSTransition in={props.index === props.activeIndex} nodeRef={ref} key={props.index} classNames={styles} timeout={900}>
         <div ref={ref} className="...">{props.content}</div>
    </CSSTransition>
    );
}

const [dayIndex, setDayIndex] = useState(0);

...

function Main() {
return (
...
<TransitionGroup component={null}>
  <CSSTransition nodeRef={someRef} key={dayIndex} classNames={styles} timeout={1000}>
     {
     props.days.map((content, index) => (
       <Animation content={content} index={index} key={index} activeIndex={dayIndex}/>
      ))
     }
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
...
)  
}
```